# How to combine multiple rows data until next row value is not null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have data like this and there is no id column to group, for example:

```
A
B
C
NULL
F
D
R
NULL
R
T
G
```

Expected output:

```
ABC
FDR
RTG
```

Comment: . . Your question makes no sense unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Is it possible to update one extra column with rownumber specifying each group like below.    A 1, B 1, C 1, NULL 1, F 2, D 2, R 2, etc..

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. One option uses a cumulative sum to define the groups, then aggregation - but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, I assumed `id`.

```
select string_agg(val, '') within group (order by id) vals
from (
    select 
        val,
        sum(case when val is null then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) grp
    from mytable
) t
group by grp
order by grp
```

If there may be consecutive `null`s, then you need a `where` clause in the outer query:

```
select string_agg(val, '') within group (order by id) vals
from (
    select 
        val,
        sum(case when val is null then 1 else 0 end) over(order by id) grp
    from mytable
) t
where val is not null 
group by grp
order by grp
```

You could also use window counts to build the groups:

```
select string_agg(val, '') within group (order by id) vals
from (
    select 
        val,
        count(*)   over(order by id) cnt1,
        count(val) over(order by id) cnt2
    from mytable
) t
group by cnt1 - cnt2
order by cnt1 - cnt2
```

Comment: MSSQL Server 2014